# Horizontal multiple choice option in google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps, google-forms

I am not quite familiar with the google docs form. My sister requests to make her multiple choice options in her survey form appear horizontal just like [this](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeb3iHt2SWWYxk1uG4RCdkFCaNr8fq0TtrIXgMQHWSkJ5TLUw/viewform?c=0&w=1) form (see image below)

[image: horizontal multiple choice options]

Now my question is, how can I make horizontal multiple choice options? If it is done with a script/markup language it's fine for me.

Comment: Script is not required. Use **multiple choice grid** as a question type while creating the google form. Explore it and you will know how to use it.

Comment: Where can I find the **multiple choice grid**? I got both **grid** and **multiple choice** menu in the drop-down list, but they are different.

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thank you so much @ShyamKansagra

Answer (score 0):

[image: linear scale]

choose linear scale instead of multiple choice
after that press preview and you will get the request result